# Adding extension method to ParallelQuery

Tags: c#, parallel-extensions

I built a concurrent list class that implements the interfaces `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

My goal is to be able to write:

```
IEnumrable<string> MyConcurrentList1 = new ConcurrentList<string>();

MyConcurrentList1.AsParallel().MyExtantionMethod_ADD("aaaa");
```

**I want to be able to call the method I wrote in the `ConcurrentList<T>` from the extenstion method of the `ParallelQuery`!**

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to ask: how to add a extension method for behind the `AsParallel()`.

It's simple: the method returns a `ParallelQuery`. So use something like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void MyExtantionMethod_ADD(this ParallelQuery query, string parameter1)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No! its not possibole to use it with out sendding the list we are using at as a parameter to this extenstion method

Comment: Which list do you mean? If you mean `MyConcurrentList`, you should not add your extension method to `AsParallel`, but to the list itself.

Comment: I want to be able to call the method I wrote in the ConcurrentList<T> from the extenstion method of the ParallelQuery! is it possibol from your expirience?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is the relation between the `AsParallel` and the extension method. If you really need to, you can add the list as second parameter, but I wonder why...

Comment: I tought on what you say and you are write. I want to be able to use the ParallelEnumerable methods on my list. There no point to wrtie them fromt he beggining.